# How to mirror a numpy matrix on y=-x axis?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mirror

Pretent I have a numpy array loaded with vectors as so:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3],
             [0, 0, 4, 5],
             [0, 0, 0, 6],
             [0, 0, 0, 0])
```

How can I mirror the array on `y=-x` axis to look as so?

```
>>a
[[0, 1, 2, 3],
 [1, 0, 4, 5],
 [2, 4, 0, 6],
 [3, 5, 6, 0]]
```

Comment: What, like `a + a.T`?

Comment: coldspeed yes, like that. is it really a duplicate? either way, I would mark your answer as correct if posted as solution

Comment: Yes, your question does not need the diagonal to be cleared but otherwise they are more or less the same.